# Contains and Custom Label in Rule Criteria - Workflow

Tags: workflow

I have a `picklist field-XYZ` which contains a lot of `values.Lets say (A,b,c,d...z)`
I am trying to write a rule criteria which will execute if the picklist value is any of the following (A,b,c...p).So instead of mentioning all the values in rule criteria , i created a `custom label` and put the values (a,b,c,d..p) in that and wrote the following in the rule criteria :

```
CONTAINS(TEXT(XYZ__c) ,$Label.CustomLabel))
```

This is not working even is the value of the picklist is equal to the one mentioned in the Custom Label.I guess the `CONTAINS` function is matching the whole value of custom label with Picklist.Is there other workaround/solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your `CONTAINS` function is matching the whole value of custom label. You may have to create separate labels for each picklist values. Hopefully the picklist values are not so many, otherwise you may end of creating lots of label.

The logic will be like this:

```
OR(
    CONTAINS(TEXT(XYZ__c) ,$Label.CustomLabelA),
    CONTAINS(TEXT(XYZ__c) ,$Label.CustomLabelB)
)
```

Comment: That's the issue @Santanu .I will have to create a lot of labels. That's what i am trying to avoid. Any other approach?

Comment: Only other approach is playing around with apex code

Answer (score 1):

Labels don't get evaluated as part of workflow rule, you can refer https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_rules_define.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

I know this is over 4 years old but wanted to share for anyone who might stumble across this as well...

Samir actually had it correct, it's just backward. No need to create more than one Custom Label. Check it out:

```
CONTAINS(TEXT(XYZ__c) ,$Label.CustomLabel))
```

...needs to be...

```
CONTAINS($Label.CustomLabel, TEXT(XYZ__c))
```

Explaination:
The syntax of the CONTAINS function is CONTAINS(does this contain, this text?). So Samir's code was asking, "*Does XYZ__c contain 'a,b,c,d...z'?*" which is false. But a true statement, assuming XYZ__c is a single letter of the alphabet, is, "*Does 'a,b,c,d...z' contain the letter in XYZ__c?*"

I hope this helps :)